# SQL - Finding foreign key ID associated with a combination of multiple/variable table variable rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In a Microsoft SQL Server stored procedure, I have table variable, `@PlayerComboStrategy`, with a variable number of rows, and columns `PLAYER_ID`, `POSITION_CODE`, `STATUS_CODE`.

I am looking for the most efficient way to retrieve the `STRATEGY_ID` associated with the exact combination of all of my table variable rows, if it exists. In other words, how can I find the `STRATEGY_ID` involving all of the `PLAYER_IDs` with their specific `POSITION_CODE` and `STATUS_CODE`. In the event that it does not exists, I will proceed with its creation in my stored procedure.

I was thinking of pulling a list of all of the `STRATEGY_IDs` for each rows matching the combination of `PLAYER_ID`, `POSITION_CODE` and `STATUS_CODE` and see if there is a common ID between the lists. However, this will fail if, for example, three players (and their position and status code) are associated with a strategy, and the exact same combination plus one (or many) extra players are associated with another strategy. That being said, the `STRATEGY_ID` retrieved must be built from x number of rows from `PLAYER_STRATEGY` matching the x number of rows from `@PlayerComboStrategy`.

An example of `@PlayerComboStrategy`

```
+-----------+---------------+-------------+
| PLAYER_ID | POSITION_CODE | STATUS_CODE |
+-----------+---------------+-------------+
|        33 |             2 |           2 |
|        23 |             4 |           1 |
+-----------+---------------+-------------+
```

A sample of `PLAYER_STRATEGY`:

```
+-------------------+-------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+
| PLAYER_STATEGY_ID | STRATEGY_ID | PLAYER_ID | POSITION_CODE | STATUS_CODE |
+-------------------+-------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+
|              1490 |         511 |        64 |             2 |           2 |
|              1491 |         511 |        33 |             2 |           2 |
|              1492 |         511 |        23 |             4 |           1 |
|              1493 |         512 |        33 |             2 |           2 |
|              1494 |         512 |        23 |             5 |           1 |
|              1495 |         513 |        33 |             2 |           2 |
|              1496 |         513 |        23 |             4 |           1 |
|              1497 |         514 |        33 |             2 |           2 |
+-------------------+-------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+
```

For this example, I would want `STRATEGY_ID = 513` to be found.

[image: relationship diagram]

Comment: This would easier for others if you provided the table structure as ddl instead of an image. Also the structure for your table variable and some sample data for it. One question....you said you want to create the strategy if it doesn't exist. Pretty sure I know what that means but what about when there is a player that doesn't exist? You don't seem to have the name in your table variable. The same issue with creating a new strategy...you don't have a name.

Comment: @SeanLange, I added some sample data to help out. As for your question, if the player does not exists, it is created in the stored procedure before creating the table variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to tackle this. I included a fully working example so you can see a nice and easy way to share data. :) There are multiple ways you can tackle this kind of thing but this is what came to my mind first.

```
declare @PlayerStrategy table
(
    PLAYER_STATEGY_ID int
    , STRATEGY_ID int
    , PLAYER_ID int
    , POSITION_CODE int
    , STATUS_CODE int
)

insert @PlayerStrategy values
(1490, 511, 64, 2, 2)
, (1491, 511, 33, 2, 2)
, (1492, 511, 23, 4, 1)
, (1493, 512, 33, 2, 2)
, (1494, 512, 23, 5, 1)
, (1495, 513, 33, 2, 2)
, (1496, 513, 23, 4, 1)
, (1497, 514, 33, 2, 2)

declare @PlayerComboStrategy table
(
    PLAYER_ID int
    , POSITION_CODE int
    , STATUS_CODE int
)

insert @PlayerComboStrategy values
(33, 2, 2)
, (23, 4, 1)


select ps.STRATEGY_ID
from @PlayerStrategy ps
join @PlayerComboStrategy pcs on ps.PLAYER_ID = pcs.PLAYER_ID
                                        and ps.POSITION_CODE = pcs.POSITION_CODE
                                        and ps.STATUS_CODE = pcs.STATUS_CODE
group by ps.STRATEGY_ID
having count(ps.PLAYER_ID) = (select count(*) from @PlayerComboStrategy)
    and count(ps.PLAYER_ID) = (select count(*) from @PlayerStrategy ps2 where ps2.STRATEGY_ID = ps.STRATEGY_ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH matching_strategies AS (
    SELECT strategy_id, COUNT(*) AS matching_strategies
    FROM @PlayerComboStrategy p
    JOIN PLAYER_STRATEGY s
        ON p.player_id = s.player_id
        AND p.position_code = s.position_code
        AND p.status_code = s.status_code
    GROUP BY strategy_id ),
total_strategies AS (
    SELECT p.strategy_id, COUNT(*) AS total_strategies
    FROM PLAYER_STRATEGY p
    JOIN matching_strategies s
        ON p.strategy_id = s.strategy_id
    GROUP BY p.strategy_id )
SELECT ms.strategy_id
FROM matching_strategies ms
JOIN total_strategies ts
    ON ms.strategy_id = ts.strategy_id
    AND ms.matching_strategies = ts.total_strategies
    AND matching_strategies = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @PlayerComboStrategy)
```

The first CTE will give you counts of all of your strategies which match to a player. The second will get the total count of players on a strategy for those which match one of the players we're looking for. The final select will check for those who's player counts match the total count, and match the total number of players being looked for.